# Hi. I am new to react and have a query re optimum setup procedures

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

The following package.json contains a lot of dependencies and a few devDependencies stuff but barring a few files  it seems to have all I need excepting a few npm install commands for reactstrap, bootstrap, react-bootstrap

```
{
  "name": "react-tutorials",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
      "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
      "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
      "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },

  "devDependencies": {},
     "scripts": {
         "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


// Additional dependencies and devDependencies
npm install --save reactstrap react-addons-transition-group react-addons-css-transition-group react react-dom 

npm install react react-dom bootstrap react-bootstrap babel-preset-react webpack webpack-dev-server --save
npm install webpack css-loader style-loader file-loader url-loader babel-core
```

What is the optimal way to create a file tree for your react project via npm and what react-*** setup packages are not too difficult for a novice such as myself? Please don't suggest create-react-app - I love it but its limited. Also, can all dependencies and devDependencies be installed via npm all at once or with some files interfere with others which I've noticed before I think.

Comment: apologies for my mistakes re protocol and/or poor query detail or execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run each of the commands `npm install --save package-here` it will add that package to your package.json automatically.  When you're ready to install your project from the root directory you run `npm install` only and it will install everything in your package.json into a node_modules folder.  Other than that you should not have to change anything with your packages as far as file structure.

In addition, when you want to add a package to your dev-devependencies run `npm install --save-dev` or just dependencies `npm install --save`.

Comment: Thanks mate! I have a few more questions but I probably shouldnt place them here. Cheers ears :)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to the wonderful world of react! If this answer has helped you at all, please mark it as accepted :)